# How do create dynamic bash script for raspberry pi 4 in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have a script on raspberry pi 4 that takes three variables. These variables are generated by matlab and I need to run this script for it. The problem is that every time I try to generate this bash command, I get an error. I'm currently using Matlab Support Package for Raspberry Pi Hardware

Is it possible to do what I'm thinking? How can I do it?
Here's my trial and error returned.

Attempt 1:

```
comando = convertStringsToChars(strcat(['python Desktop/R3D5/motor.py '], [' '], [ang], [' '], [dir]));
system(raspi, comando)

Error:
Error executing command "python Desktop/R3D5/motor.py 100 1". Details:

STDERR:   File "Desktop/R3D5/motor.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file Desktop/R3D5/motor.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see
http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

STDOUT:

Error in R3D5_main (line 31)
R3D5.moveBase(' 100', ' 1');
```

Attempt 2:

```
 system(raspi, 'python Desktop/R3D5/base.py '+ ang + ' ' + dir)

Error:
Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation.

Error in R3D5/moveBase (line 49)
            system(R3D5.r, 'python Desktop/R3D5/base.py '+ ang +' ' + dir)

Error in R3D5_main (line 31)
R3D5.moveBase('100', ' 1');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried executing the python script with parameters outside of matlab - seems to be an encoding issue with the file.

Comment: ... _see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details_

Comment: first code shows problem in first line with char which have code '\xc3' - `print('\xc3')` gives me `Ã` - so check what you have in first line, and if you use native chars then remove them, write only in `English` (`ASCII code`). Eventually you may need to add line `-*- encoding: utf-8 -*-` (in first or second line) to inform Python that it has to use `utf-8` instead of `ascii` (but this problem was usually in Python 2)